# how to delete everything between the brackets?

Tags: python

```
s="function(function()function(hii))wait function(function(byee))"
```

for this string i need output like this

```
function()wait function()
```

how to delete the content between the brackets?

```
def filter_line(line):
    count=0
    ignore=False
    result=[]
    for c in line:
        if c==")" and count!=0:
            count=0
            ignore=False
        if not ignore:
            result.append(c)
        if c=="(" :
            ignore=True
            count=1
        print(count)
    return "".join(result)
```

i got this code from here and i got output for my problem as

```
function()function())wait function())
```

Comment: My first attempt was to use regex but it would not account for closing and opening of brackets, so the solution would be to use a stack/queue.

Comment: You might want to use [regex](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
s = "function(function()function(hii))wait function(function(byee))"
brack = 0
t = ""
for letter in s:
    if letter == '(':
        brack += 1
        if brack == 1:
            t += letter
        continue
    elif letter == ')':
        brack -= 1
        if brack == 0:
            t += letter
        continue
    
    if not brack:
        t += letter
```

output:

> function()wait function()

You can change the solution a bit and optimize it for readability, behavior, and performance, but I chose to keep it similar to yours.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the regex way

```
input_str = "function(function()function(hii))wait function(function(byee))"
pattern = r"(function\().*(\)wait function\().*(\))"
output = re.sub(pattern, r"\1\2\3", input_str)
print(output)
```

Output:

```
function()wait function()
```